# Is the Monk's Resolve skill affected by thorns?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

I use `Sweeping Winds` or `Cyclone` in order to apply this debuff on ranged attackers; but I want to know if thorns damage applies the debuff, and if `Resolve` even works on ranged attacks.

Which brings me to another question on how Resolve works. I notice that it does not affect arcane, molten or cold enchanted damage from elites, but packs with fire-chains seem to do a lot less damage given the same resistances and armor (gauging on how fast my HP pool drops). If arcane is not affected by Resolve, can I assume all ranged abilities are not affected by Resolve?

Comment: Arcane Enchant, Plagued, Desecrator, Molten, (Frozen?) are all abilities where the monsters are not the origin of the attack.  I am not sure about Firechain.  I would assume that ranged attacks that originate as an attack from a monster would still be subject to Resolve's effect.

Answer (score 1):

Thorns damage **does not apply on-hit effects** always; for example Life on Hit is not triggered by thorns (apparently life leech does work). If Resolve is counted as an on-hit, then thorns won't work - also, I doubt that thorns damage counts as 'Damage ***you*** deal to the enemy'. As such, I'm quite sure that Thorns won't affect `Resolve`, but haven't done any testing to confirm it.

Arcane Enchanted is a spell cast on the ground and not damage done directly from the monster; you still get the reduction from normal ranged attacks (skeleton archer shots etc.) It should work similar to how hydra or sentry won't proc life on hit (afaik) since their damage is not directly caused by the wizard or DH.